# How to add a new role in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I am trying to configure a new role in Symfony2. I edited the `security.yml` file as following:

```
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_Administrator:  [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        ROLE_Doctor: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_Patient:  ROLE_USER
access_control:
        - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_Administrator }
```

However, when I tried to login, I always got:

`Access Denied
403 Forbidden
- AccessDeniedHttpException
1 linked Exception: AccessDeniedException »`

I read the document in the [official Symfony2 site](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html). I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your security.yml, in your hierarchy and in your access control the roles must be the same.

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_Administrator:  [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    ROLE_Doctor: ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_Patient:  ROLE_USER
access_control:
    - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

You define the ROLE that you need. You can call the admin as ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_Administrator, as you want, but in every situation you have to use it with the same name. If you use two different name Symfony just think that you are referring to two different kind of role. Then, in your role_hierarchy, you can define that the ROLE_Doctor include the ROLE_ADMIN and so on...
I haven't seen you controller, but surely you defined your user with a Role not allowed to see the path: ^/ because you passed the firewall (you are logged in) but not the access control (you are not allowed to see this page).

Attention because

```
    ROLE_Doctor: ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_Patient:  ROLE_USER
```

In the above configuration, users with ROLE_Doctor role will also have the ROLE_ADMIN role and ROLE_Patient will also have ROLE_USER role. Documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried it and still got the same error.

Comment: How do you set the ROLE in your User? Probably the error is there, show your controller.

Comment: you were right! I did some things wrong in the controller. Could you explain a little bit when the `ROLE_Administrator` is used? For example, in your code, you used `ROLE_ADMIN` instead of `ROLE_Administrator` So, I have never seen when/how we use it.

Comment: I edited the answer. If you have more doubts, just ask!

Comment: Great explanation. Just one more question. Why you use `- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }` instead of `- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_Administrator }`

Comment: I'm used to use ROLE_ADMIN, only this. It's more short and coherent with the other roles! For example I use ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN. 
But really, it's just a matter of "name", you can choose what you want; the importance is that in your controller you set the correct one.